# In ggplot2, can borders of bars be changed on only one side? (color, thickness)

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, bar-chart, geom-bar

I know, 3D Barcharts are a sin. But i´m asked to do them and as a trade-off i suggested to only make a border with a slightly darker color than the bar´s on the top and the right side of the bar. Like that, the bars would have some kind of "shadow" (urgh) but at least you still would be able to compare them.

Is there any way to do this?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility, using two sets of `geom_bar`. The first set, the green ones, are made slightly higher and offset to the right. I borrow the data from @Didzis Elferts.

```
ggplot(data = df2) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.numeric(clarity) + 0.1, y = V1 + 100),
           width = 0.8, fill = "green", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.numeric(clarity), y = V1),
           width = 0.8, stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "clarity",
                     breaks = as.numeric(df2$clarity),
                     labels = levels(df2$clarity))+
  ylab("count")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you already said - 3D barcharts are "bad". You can't do it directly in ggplot2 but here is a possible workaround for this.

First, make new data frame that contains levels of clarity and corresponding count for each level.

```
library(plyr)
df2<-ddply(diamonds,.(clarity),nrow)
```

Then in `ggplot()` call use new data frame and `clarity` as x values and `V1` (counts) as y values and add `geom_blank()` - this will make x axis with levels we need. Then add `geom_rect()` to produce shading for bars - here `xmin` and `xmax` values are made `as.numeric()` from `clarity` and constant is added - for `xmin` constant should be less than half of bars width and `xmax` constant larger than half of bars width. `ymin` is 0 and `ymax` is `V1` (counts) plus some constant. Finally add `geom_bar(stat="identity")` above this shadow to plot actually barplot.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(clarity,V1)) + geom_blank()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.numeric(clarity)-0.38,
                xmax=as.numeric(clarity)+.5,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=V1+250),fill="green")+
  geom_bar(width=0.8,stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a workaround but Stephen Few is crying and my eyes are bleeding.