# Add shadow effect ggplot2 bars (barplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to show poorer design choices in plots.  One of the ink wasting, potentially distracting effects people use if a shadow effect of bars.  I'd like to make **ggplot2** do this.  The basic thought I had was to make a first semitransparent layer of bars slightly higher and shifted to the right.  I can get the slightly higher but not the slightly to the right:

```
dat <- data_frame(
    School =c("Franklin", "Washington", "Jefferson", "Adams", "Madison", "Monroe"),
    sch = seq_along(School),
    count = sort(c(13, 17, 12, 14, 3, 22), TRUE),
    Percent = 100*round(count/sum(count), 2)
)

dat[["School"]] <- factor(dat[["School"]], levels = c("Franklin", 
    "Washington", "Jefferson", "Adams", "Madison", "Monroe"))

ggplot(dat) +
   geom_bar(aes(x = School, weight=Percent + .5), alpha=.1, width = .6) +
   geom_bar(aes(x = School, weight=Percent, fill = School), width = .6) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

This attempt gives the following warning and that transparent layer is ignored (which is sensible):

```
ggplot(dat) +
   geom_bar(aes(x = School + .2, weight=Percent + .5), alpha=.1, width = .6) +
   geom_bar(aes(x = School, weight=Percent, fill = School), width = .6) +
   theme_bw()

## Warning messages:
## 1: In Ops.factor(School, 0.2) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
## 2: In Ops.factor(School, 0.2) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Not a full answer I think, but try reversing the order of the `geom_bar` layers and explicitly converting `School` to integers for the second layer (either in the data frame, or in the `aes()` call).

Comment: ...using `y` and `stat = "identity"` rather than `weight` seems to get even closer to what you want.

Comment: ...I can do the gray rectangles in back (i.e. first) if I use a continuous scale for both layers, but of course that clobbers the x axis labeling, and you'd have fix that manually. (Sorry for the sketching this out in comments...)

Comment: @joran your think aloud helped me get there too.  That's much better learning than you just giving me a solution.

Comment: See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927114/in-ggplot2-can-borders-of-bars-be-changed-on-only-one-side-color-thickness/

Comment: @Henrik different purpose but same approach good call on linking them.

Comment: @TylerRinker "Stephen Few is crying and my eyes are bleeding" ;)

Comment: Well you can't know good without showing bad.  See  http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/data-looks-better-naked/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you're looking for...?

```
ggplot(dat) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = as.integer(School) + .2, y= Percent - .5),stat = "identity", alpha=.2,width = 0.6) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = as.integer(School), y=Percent, fill = School),stat = "identity",width = 0.6) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6,labels = as.character(dat$School)) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joran exactly.  Your hints had got me there and this seals it.

Comment: I like the top perspective better anyway so this was helpful to see.

Answer (score 6):

Using what @joran gave me this works (Thanks Joran):

```
ggplot(dat) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = School, y=Percent), fill=NA, color=NA, width = .6, stat = "identity") +
    geom_bar(aes(x = sch + .075, y=Percent + .5), alpha=.3, width = .6, stat = "identity") +
    geom_bar(aes(x = School, y=Percent, fill = School), width = .6, stat = "identity")
```

The key is:

1. Add another layer before the transparent layer that is identical to the color bars, but don't fill or color them (use `NA`)
2. Make a numeric version of the factor (in my case I had made `sch` but didn't work without previous step
3. Don't use `weight` but instead use `y` & `stat = "identity"`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Oh someone already answered this, but here's mine anyway. Since you are just drawing pictures here, you could use geom_rect:

```
xwidth <- 0.5
xoffset <- 0.05
yoffset <- 0.05

my_dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=5:1, labels=letters[1:5])

ggplot(my_dat) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=x+xoffset, xmax=x+xwidth+xoffset, 
                ymin=0, ymax=y+yoffset), 
            fill='grey', alpha=0.8) +

  geom_rect(aes(xmin=x, xmax=x+xwidth, 
                ymin=0, ymax=y, fill=labels)) +

  scale_x_discrete(labels=my_dat$labels, breaks=my_dat$x) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]