# How to replicate this excel 3d histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, 3d, histogram

I am looking to reproduce roughly the following 3d histogram (made in Excel) in R.  The trick is that the labels should fall *between* the Justice names, as the bars are meant to delineate the number of times certain justices voted against other justices. [image]

You can use the following code to generate the data:

```
cutpoints <- c(0, 22, 16, 12, 13, 7, 16, 13, 20)

justice_names <- c("Peckham", "Brewer", "Shiras", 
    "Fuller", "Gray", "Brown", "McKenna", "White", "Harlan")
```

Comment: You can't draw 3d plots in ggplot2. I assume this was an intentional decision by the developers, because they generally don't include problematic plot types in ggplot, and 3d plots like this one [distort data by not using proportional ink](https://callingbullshit.org/tools/tools_proportional_ink.html)

Comment: I've answered a question on simulating [Excel graphics with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862606/excel-graphics-with-ggplot2/) before. Not my proudest moment, but it can be done. I strongly recommend simply shifting the labels as per pwrignall's answer below, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough reproduction, omitting the 3D.

Plotting the x-axis as numeric and applying labels after allows you to shift the labels to the right by half a mark.

```
library(ggplot2)

cutpoints <- c(0, 22, 16, 12, 13, 7, 16, 13, 20)

justice_names <- c("Peckham",
                   "Brewer",
                   "Shiras",
                   "Fuller",
                   "Gray",
                   "Brown",
                   "McKenna",
                   "White",
                   "Harlan")

hist_data <- data.frame(justice_names, cutpoints, order = seq(1:9))

hist_data$justice_names <-
  factor(hist_data$justice_names, levels = hist_data$justice_names)

ggplot(hist_data, aes(x = order, y = cutpoints)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = hist_data$order + 0.5, # Shift labels by 0.5
                     labels = hist_data$justice_names) +
  geom_text(aes(label = cutpoints), vjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.25) +
  labs(x = "Justice", y = "Number",
       title = "Fig A-1. Number of Cutpoints, 1899-1901") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(linetype = "dashed"))
```